# Cross compile in mac m1 - build for x86_64 linux

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, prql

I want to build cdylib crate of my repo https://github.com/doki23/prql-java in my mac m1.

My operations are:

```
rustup target add x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

but I met the problem:

> = note: ld: unknown option: --version-script=/var/folders/df/1lz9t40n171_5550cy_f1h3c0000gn/T/rustczqz5TV/list
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

How to build a x86_64 linux lib in mac m1?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the proper `linker` and `ar` paths:

Add the below lines to your `${HOME}/.cargo/config`:

```
[target.x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu]
ar = "[PATH_TO_CROSS_TOOLCHAIN]/bin/ar"
linker = "[PATH_TO_CROSS_TOOLCHAIN]/bin/clang"
```

You can also use the `ld` of the cross toolchain instead of clang if you have, say `gcc`.

Assuming that you want to build for android `x86_64`;
Add this to your `${HOME}/.cargo/config` file

```
[target.x86_64-linux-android]
ar = "${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android-ar"
linker = "/${ANDROID_NDK_HOME}/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/x86_64-linux-android28-clang"
```

Comment: Any hints as to how exactly install the cross toolchain?